# p:commandButton does not work in the last ajax request

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I have to Tab in selectoneButton as "request" and "archive". In that tab I have information that is called with ajax. In that information I need to have a button As "acceptCommonButton"  and "noNowCommonButton" so when a User clicks on the "acceptCommonButton" button it calls the "acceptRequest" method. When a user Clicks on "noNowCommonButton" button it calls to "notNowRequest" method.

My problem is that the Button Works until the last request is in "archive" Tab. It means that when the last request is in "request" tab my Button does not work. it's too Weird!!!! 
I think the problem here is caused by DataGrid.

could you please see my Code?!!

```
<table style="width: 100%">
        <tr>
            <td>                    
                <p:selectOneButton  value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.filterType}">  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{inviteRequest_msg.request}" itemValue="request"/>  
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{inviteRequest_msg.archive}" itemValue="archive" />   
                    <f:ajax event="change"  render="requestDataGrid" />             

                </p:selectOneButton>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <p:dataGrid id="requestDataGrid" var="tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo" 
                            value="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.filterBusinessRequest()}" columns="1" rows="22" >
                    <p:column>
                        <div>
                            <table border="0"  width="100%">
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:graphicImage value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.partySender_imageUrl}"/>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div>
                                            <table border="0" width="100%">
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <h:outputLabel value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.requestDate}"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <h:outputLabel value="#{tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.partySender_fullName}"/>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:commandButton  id="acceptCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.accept}"
                                                          actionListener="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.acceptRequest(tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.id)}" 
                                                          update="@form" process="@form">

                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </td>                              
                                    <td>
                                        <p:commandButton id="noNowCommonButton" value="#{inviteRequest_msg.notnow}"  
                                                         actionListener="#{inviteRequestManagedBean.notNowRequest(tBusinessPartnerRequestInfo.id)}" 
                                                         update="@form" process="@form">
                                        </p:commandButton>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <p:panel>
                                            <p:ajaxStatus>
                                                <f:facet name="start">
                                                    <p:graphicImage value="../resources/img/loading.gif"/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                                <f:facet name="complete">
                                                    <h:outputLabel value=""/>
                                                </f:facet>
                                            </p:ajaxStatus>
                                        </p:panel>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataGrid> 
                <p:panel>

                </p:panel>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: Your code sample has a lot of unnecessary stuff that will make it difficult to read.